# How to make POST work using router.post in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm very new to this and I'm following a [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#the-posts-page).
Basically the app is about creating posts and comments to those posts.
I've created a POST for creating posts, but I can't get POST for comments to work. I have two models:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
```

Posts model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    upvotes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
});

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function (cb) {
    this.upvotes += 1;
    this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comments model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: String,
    upvotes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    post: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

POST for posts that's working

```
router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);
    post.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

POST for comments that's not working

```
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function(req, res, next) {
    var comment = new Comment(req.body);
    comment.post = req.post;

    comment.save = function(err, comment) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        req.post.comments.push(comment);
        req.post.save(function(err, post) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            res.json(comment);
        });
    };
});
```

And I'm using the following CURL for post creation (this one is working)

```
curl --data 'title=test12&link=http://test12.com&comments=bla' http://localhost:3000/posts
```

and this one for comments that's not working

```
curl --data 'something'  http://localhost:3000/posts/58302f9662aa080ec9d75068/comments
```

The response to that call from server is:

```
POST /posts/58302f9662aa080ec9d75068/comments - - ms - -
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues:

```
comment.post = req.post
```

I think that you mean `req.params.post` here (refering to the `:post` placeholder in the URL pattern), not `req.post`.

```
comment.save = function(err, comment) { ... }
```

You probably want to *call* `comment.save`, not assign a new function to it:

```
comment.save(function(err, comment) { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

The Curl

```
curl --data 'something'  http://localhost:3000/post/58302f9662aa080ec9d75068/comments
```

Should it be?

```
curl --data 'body=mybody&author=myauthor'  http://localhost:3000/posts/58302f9662aa080ec9d75068/comments
```

Comment: Same unfortunately, empty response from server it says.

Comment: @robertklep answer below solve your problem i.e. getting params from urls and also fixing the issues with comment.save